# Different Status Bar colour for iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, view

I'm starting Developing for iOS and I want to know if someone knows how to change the status bar color like Youtube or Hangout apps do. I think that is overlaying a view but I do not know how to do it.

Thanks for all :).

[Example 1: Hangout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYff5.png)
[Example 2: Youtube.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoXxM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you'll need an overlay, it's how I would do to have an effect like in your examples:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let view: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 20))

    // We will apply a transparent black color to darken the status bar
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    view.alpha = 0.1

    self.window!.rootViewController!.view.addSubview(view)

    return true
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for reply :D! 

Yes, I have changed the navigation bar but I need to change also the Status bar color in order to difference them, for that reason I think that a view over the layer is the solution but I'm not sure of that :( ...

Comment: Ah yes sorry don't see you were speaking about the status bar.. In fact yes you need an overlay for that since the only thing you can change on the status bar is the color 'lightStyle' and 'darkStyle'. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah thats it!! Thank you so much :D!